# Permission denied using wicked_pdf

Tags: windows, ruby-on-rails-3, windows-7, wicked-pdf

I'm using

```
Windows 7  
Rails 3.2.11  
wkhtmltopdf 0.9.9
```

in gemfile

```
gem 'wicked_pdf'
```

In my initializer

```
WickedPdf.config = { :exe_path => 'C:\wkhtmltopdf' }
```

Exe is located at

```
C:\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltopdf.exe
```

When I run from rails c

```
irb(main):001:0> WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string('<h1>Hello There!</h1>')
```

I get the following error...

> "***************\"C:\wkhtmltopdf\"
>   \"file:///C:/Users/bob/bob_rail
>   s_demo/Course_Stats/wicked_pdf20130307-6328-7cuwz7.html\"
>   \"C:/Users/bob/wful
>   ts_rails_demo/Course_Stats/wicked_pdf_generated_file20130307-6328-n902yj.pdf\" *
>   **************" RuntimeError: Failed to execute: "C:\wkhtmltopdf"        "file:///C:/Users/bob/bob_rails_demo/Course_Stats/
>   wicked_pdf20130307-6328-7cuwz7.html"
>   "C:/Users/bob/bob_rails_demo/Course_S
>   tats/wicked_pdf_generated_file20130307-6328-n902yj.pdf" Error:
>   Permission denied - "C:\wkhtmltopdf"        "file:///C:/Users/bob/wful
>   ts_rails_demo/Course_Stats/wicked_pdf20130307-6328-7cuwz7.html"
>   "C:/Users/bob
>   /bob_rails_demo/Course_Stats/wicked_pdf_generated_file20130307-6328-n902yj.pd
>   f"
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/wicked_pdf-0.9
>   .4/lib/wicked_pdf.rb:50:in `rescue in pdf_from_string'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/wicked_pdf-0.9
>   .4/lib/wicked_pdf.rb:34:in`pdf_from_string'
>           from (irb):1
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
>   1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
>   1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in`start'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
>   1/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
>           from script/rails:6:in`require'
>           from script/rails:6:in `'

If I change this line to this...

```
WickedPdf.config = { :exe_path => 'C:\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltopdf.exe' }
```

Then run it in the rails command line it appears to work, but in my app Rack middleware is just hanging...

Comment: wkhtmltopdf runs fine by itself in the windows command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue, except originally I had my exe located at C:\Program Files (x86)\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltopdf.exe

So I changed it to `C:\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltopdf.exe` (which you already have) and then I made my `:exe_path` this: `:exe_path => 'C:\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltopdf.exe'`

I believe the reason you have to add the .exe in a windows environment is because windows needs to have the file explicitly pathed. Once I did this it worked like a charm.

Let me know how it goes (or went)!

Comment: i got wkhmltopdf and wkhtmltopdf.bat in my bin folder. specififying either of them is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and what did the trick for me was changing the permissions on the file:

`chmod o+w /usr/local/bundle/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.6.5/bin/`